# How can I guarantee the order of resolves in an angular App with a lot of states

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have an Angular app with a lot of states (and child states).

Some of those states have resolves.

And the app needs two pieces of data that are shared among almost all states. These data objects are requested from the API on a successful login.

The app is using angular-jwt-tokens for auth, and I store the token and the data regarding the current user in the $cookieStore, but not those extra pieces of data.

Now for the problem:

When a user refreshes the page I check if the token and user data are on the $cookieStore and if so get the extra data I need.

But if the state the user is refreshing has a resolve that depends on that data, I get an exception because the app starts that resolve before the data comes in.

Did anyone faced a similar problem? How did you solved it?

Comment: How about loading those extra data using promises as well

Comment: I do get then using promises, but since one of the requests in being done in the run method of the app (getting the user data from the cookieStore), the state resolves don't wait for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Child states inherit resolves of parent states. If a parent state resolve promise gets rejected, child state resolve won't even fire.

You can basically look at the nested states having chained promises from parent state resolves ... rejections break the chain

Thus you should should be able to set up the user resolve at top level.

Also catch these in the event `$stateChangeError` where you can return an appropriate alternate redirect. A run block is helpful for setting up this event listener.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And I do understand your point, but my problem is that I can't have every part of the data dependency in the resolves because of the user data that gets stored in the cookieStore. And this is needed because the API we're using is sessionless and we need to have a way to let users refresh the page. I am trying to tie that part in a promise in a service but I'm not sure it's the right approach

Comment: not understanding why you can't access the cookie data in the top level resolve. Any child state that gets entered directly such as a refresh will pass through that resolve first. Can inject services into `resolve`s so you can access your Auth before proceeding

Comment: Now I feel dumb :-), I wasn't even considering that. But that makes perfect sense now. Thanks